# NodeJs missing stacktrace when JSON.stringify an err

Tags: node.js, error-handling

We are trying to send out errors to a sqlite3 database when an error occurs in one of our node scripts.  We are using IPC Channel communications between processes that our main.js spawns and routes as necessary.

```
const logme = (message, type, showMessage = true) => {
    if (showMessage) {
        switch (type.toLowerCase()) {
            case 'error':
            case 'warn':
                console.error(message);
                break;
            default:
                console.log(message);
                break;
        }
    }
    if (process.send) {
        process.send({ to: 'logs', msg: { c: 'logme', a: 'thisScript', m: message, mt: type } });
    }
};

process.on('uncaughtException', err => {
    logme(`thisScript Uncaught Exception Error: ${JSON.stringify(err, null, 2)}`, 'error');
    if (process.send) {
        process.send({ to: 'main', msg: { c: 'kill', a: 'thisScript' } });
    }
});
```

On an uncaught exception, we got a message like this, however, no stacktrace was  in the object.  I thought it would be, how do we add this to the object in the future so we know where the error occurred in our code?

```
thisScript Uncaught Exception Error: {

  "message": "Cannot read property 'StorageFiles' of undefined",

  "code": "TypeError",

  "time": "2019-06-13T16:26:44.753Z"

}
```

Comment: did you try to print the `err.stack` variable explicitly?

Comment: What kind of error does the process throw here? Is it a custom Error object or the native type https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypeError?

Comment: It is not a custom error we are trying to track the error down to where in the code it happened but without the stack trace we are a little at a loss. So trying to see where it happened was our first action item.